# Laravel Blade views not showing the changes made to them

Tags: laravel, templates, laravel-4, laravel-blade

System Details : Using WAMP2.5 in Windows 64 bit
 MYSQL:5.6.17 
PHP:5.5.12 
 Apache :2.4.9
I installed laravel via composer installation . It was all fine since recently all my views stopped showing any changes made to them . This is happening to views which use Blade template only.

I have created the blade files correctly and named them with `filename.blade.php`.
My view File Structure - 
`views`
       
    `-layouts` 
                  
    `defaults.blade.php` 
       
    `show.blade.php` 
       
    `login.blade.php`

**defaults.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
      <head></head>
<body>
  <div>
   <nav></nav>

       @yield('content')

  </div>
      @yield('footerscripts')

</body>
</html>
```

**show.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.defaults')
@section('content')
    --- SOME CONTENT ---
@stop

@section('footerscripts')
     --- js scripts ---
@stop
```

The same format was working perfectly but suddenly started acting strangely.Even after refreshing many times the view doesn't change,Once i tried deleting everything inside the view page still it showed up in the browser.
There are similar question but many didn't have accepted answer and the one with some ratings didn't worked for me . I also tried re-installing fresh new WAMP copy but no Help.It only works if i change its name but if i change it back to the original one it again starts showing the old version of it.
Only happens with blade templating.

Comment: Updating the timezone in your config or in php.ini might cause Laravel to not realize that blade templates have changed.  Any chance you did that? If so, @clarkf's solution of clearing /app/storage/views should work, though you should only have to do it once.

Comment: I didn't changed the timeZone but does it checks the system's time and if the time of updation is greater, then it updates the view ? If it works like that then sure it will cause problem in my system cause my system always show wrong timing.

Answer (score 17):

If you use PhpStorm:

1. open menu `File → Settings`
2. go to `Deployment → Options` section
3. then uncheck `Preserve files timestamps` option

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure of the specifics, but this is related to how [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/filemtime) is implemented in windows (possibly related bug [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40568)).

[`Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.2.6/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php) (well, it's parent class, [`Compiler`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.2.6/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Compiler.php#L45-L66)) checks to see if a file has changed since last compilation by checking it's mtime, through [`Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php) which calls calls `filemtime()` (see [L179-188](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L179-L188)). Evidently this is failing to report properly on your system.

First, ensure that the `app/storage/views` directory has read, write and delete permissions.  If this doesn't help, the simplest solution would be to clear the `app/storage/views/` directory whenever making a change.

Comment: If it just checks the System Time and updates the view only when if the time of updating was greater than the old one then I think probably its the problem of my System Time . It always shows wrong timing maybe CMOS battery problem .But this also happened in my friend's lappy(which has no Time problems) but it remained for a short duration ,after a while when he refreshed the view was updated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue , reason was I am doing uploads remote, but the time on my computer was different than what that was on my server

Answer (score 1):

I got very easy solution, I was having same project in two folders, I was editing one and php artisan was running on other, when get to that project where php server was running in it and made changes it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your cmd(command prompt) or terminal type and press enter...
   php artisan view:clear

For this to work, your terminal should be pointed to your root directory of your laravel installation/folder

2. Or delete files in the folder
   storage/framework/views

In order to avoid the parsing of Blade files on each reload, Laravel is designed to caches  views after Blade is parsed, to avoid re-parsing the blades on each reload.

3. Or make sure you are editing the right view, in the right Laravel Installation.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `npm run production` or `npm run dev`

It solved my problem:
I had the same issue except my controller methods also did not want to reflect changes along with views.  I tried the following commands:

```
user:/var/www/html/website$ php artisan cache:clear
Application cache cleared!
user:/var/www/html/website$ php artisan config:clear
Configuration cache cleared!
user:/var/www/html/website$ php artisan route:clear
Route cache cleared!
user:/var/www/html/website$ php artisan view:clear
Compiled views cleared!
```

Nothing changed.

I echoed an incorrect variable from a controller method.  Nada!

I changed the `app.css?v=2` file version. In the silence that followed after... there was no difference.

I cleared my browser cache.

I manually deleted:
`bootstrap/cache/config.php`
`framework/sessions/*`
`framework/views/*`

No changes and finally I ran the command `npm run production` and bingo!  Try it, it will save you 2 and a half hours of frustration and radical thoughts.

Laravel/framework v5.6

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache and restart php-fpm. That solved it for me.