# Blade view not reflecting changes

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am developing a Laravel(5.2.29) project in a Windows environment and testing it on a Chrome browser.

I have made some changes on a Blade file using the atom text editor and then refreshed my page and noticed that suddenly it has stopped reflecting the changes (it's loading the old Blade file).

I've tried the following:

- Restarted the browser
- Clearing browser cache
- Running `php artisan cache:clear`
- Running `composer dumpautoload`
- Deleting the Blade file (and got a *view not found* error). Then created a new Blade file with the same name, with no content, and refreshed the page.

No matter what, the code displayed on the browser is always the same (old) version and not the content of the Blade file.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In order to avoid the parsing of Blade files on each reload, Laravel caches the views after Blade is processed. I've experienced some situations where the source (view file) is updated but the cache file is not "reloaded". In these cases, all you need to do is to delete the cached views and reload the page.

The cached view files are stored in `storage/framework/views`.

Comment: this worked..i have deleted all the views under framework. thanks.

Comment: I tried the same but I still see old view's cached version.

Comment: Cache is actually empty for me

Comment: I have a similar situation, but it not only affects the views but the controllers as well. I believe the issue is related to the difference in time between the testing server and my laptop. Unfortunately I haven't been able to resolve it no matter what I do :(

Comment: Just as an update, I was able to resolve this issue by pointing both my development environment and the testing server to the same time server so both have the exact same time. Hope this helps

Comment: @danboh How did you point your development environment to the same time server?

Comment: If you do this you'll have problems in your app. Use `php artisan view:clear` instead

Comment: @ConnorLeech can you expand on that? What issues have you experienced with this? Thanks

Comment: I was getting an error that the path to this directory not found and Laravel error screen. I recreated the directory manually but think using built in artisan commands to handle this is best practice. Related issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7295

Comment: You would think that `php artisan view:clear` would exactly do this for you, but it did not work for me, whereas manually deleting the cached view files from the `storage/framework/views` folder worked.

Comment: Php artisan cache:clear didn't work but manually deleting the framework/views folder worked for me

Comment: I realized finally. There was a similar xml . In other viwes folder. Have checked the path out and it plays ok again

Comment: @danboh, your answer resolved my issue. My Computers time somehow got behind and affected my code changes from reflecting.

Comment: This worked for me, I deleted the old folder and then created the new empty one.

Answer (score 57):

Run this command from terminal

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: It is there in 5.2 as per op requirement.  Run  php artisan and check yourself before downvoting this answer.

Comment: This actually worked for me. This is just to confirm, the command do exist and it got rid of the cached view I was getting.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it for me

Answer (score 17):

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
rm -rf bootstrap/cache/*/*
```

- Delete Cache/OPcache from PHP (fpm) of your Nginx/Apache server.

Comment: ...one (or all) of these worked. I was too lazy to run them one by one and check if it worked after each

Answer (score 16):

If you use PhpStorm, uncheck `Preserve files timestamps` deployment option:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42534996/2453148

Comment: This is it for me - the problem only started when I started to use PHPStorm midway through a project so I knew it wasn't anything with laravel!

Answer (score 6):

Clear the cache and clear the cached blade files:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also check if `opcache` enabled, in that case you need to clear your opcache cache.

Comment: This was it for me. `service php7.0-fpm reload` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Like Can Gelis mentionned in a comment. For me the solution was to reload PHP FPM

`service php7.2-fpm reload`

Comment: You saved my sanity. I've been working on this for a few hours now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively if other suggested methods did not work, you can rename your files to different names. Refresh their corresponding web pages to start using new file name reference. Then you can rename the files back to your preferred names after the new pages to reflect their changes.

Comment: @Michel please explain more. It does work as long as you will change file name to new name and back to the original name after refreshing your page.

Answer (score 0):

I have  cleared all cashs and uploaded folders but didnt see  changes.
Thus, if you have placed the project on a public hosting and don't have access to  console then try to set deployment via your IDE (mine is phpstorm, e.g.)and set it to autoload mode. Then you'll get it working by changing something in the problem blade and by pressing cntrl+s(save) shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

clear cache didn't work for me, but I just edited the file and saved it again, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions have resolved this issue for me. Tried all php artisan options and the php code is not updating.

Only solution i've found is restarting the docker container that the code is running inside.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, cache clear commands and deleting the storage framework view folder but nothing worked. Finally, this command worked for me perfectly.

```
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: If you read what `optimize` does, this will create a cache of the framework bootstrap files, which is probably not desirable for cache busting. In any case, this did not work for me and neither did running `php artisan optimize:clear` beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

In case you try everything and nothing works. I recommend that you simply create a view under another name and the problem will be fixed

Example:

```
welcome.blade.php
```

change to

```
newview.blade.php
```

*copy and paste code to new view*

In controller just point to new view:

```
return view('newview');
```