# Laravel blade views not showing updated content

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, shared-hosting

I have a Laravel site running on a GoDaddy share hosting plan. I'm on PHP version 7.1. It has functioned fine up until yesterday. Now the blade views no longer show changes that occur on the database.

I see that the POST functions are working, as the changes are reflected in the database. They're just not showing up in the views themselves.

I've tried to clear the view cache as suggested here: [Blade view not reflecting changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503627/blade-view-not-reflecting-changes)

I have also changed the timezone in config/app to 'America/Phoenix' to try and match godaddy's servers: https://www.godaddy.com/community/cPanel-Hosting/How-To-Change-Timezone-on-a-shared-server/td-p/102712

I've contacted GoDaddy's tech support and they couldn't find anything they believed could cause it.

Example Route:

```php
//Resource
Route::resource('beer', 'BeerController');
```

Example Controller:

```php
    public function update(Request $request, Beer $beer)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required']);

        $beer->update(request(['name', 'beer_style_id', 'style', 'abv', 'ibus', 'srm', 'brewery_id', 'on_tap']));

        return view('beers.show', compact('beer'));
    }
```

Example View

```html
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <h1>Edit {{ $beer->name }}</h1>

            <hr />

            {!! Form::model($beer, ['route' => ['beer.update', $beer->id], 'method' => 'patch']) !!}

            <div class="form-group">

                {!! Form::label('name', 'Name') !!}
                {!! Form::text('name', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                {!! Form::label('brewery_id', 'Brewery') !!}<br />
                {!! Form::select('brewery_id', $breweries, null, ['placeholder' => 'Select Brewery', 'class' => 'custom-select mb-2', 'style' => 'width:100%;'])  !!}

            </div>

            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">

                <div class="col">

                    {!! Form::label('beer_style_id', 'Style Family') !!}<br />
                    {!! Form::select('beer_style_id', $beerstyles, null, ['placeholder' => 'Select Style', 'class' => 'custom-select mb-2', 'style' => 'width:100%;'])  !!}

                </div>

                <div class="col">

                    {!! Form::label('style', 'Style') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('style', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 1.5rem;">


                <div class="col">

                    {!! Form::label('abv', 'ABV') !!}

                    <div class="input-group">

                        {!! Form::number('abv', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'step' => '.1']) !!}

                        <span class="input-group-addon">&#37;</span>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col">

                    {!! Form::label('ibus', 'IBUs') !!}
                    {!! Form::number('ibus', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                </div>

                <div class="col">

                    {!! Form::label('srm', 'SRM') !!}
                    {!! Form::number('srm', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'step' => '.1']) !!}

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group" id="on-tap-checkbox">

                {!! Form::checkbox('on_tap', '1') !!} On Tap

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                <a href="/beer/{{ $beer->id }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>

            </div>

            @include('layouts.errors')

            {!! Form::close() !!}

        </div>

    </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Is everything working on your local?

Comment: Yes, everything is working locally. I pushed my project into a new directory on the host server and pointed to that for safe measures, and I am still experiencing the same issue. The most frustrating thing is that the site has been up for over a year now (with no updates), and the issue just started yesterday.