# How to change the text of my form in blade.php?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-blade

I'm trying to change the text of the popup form but even though I already change it in `blade.php` still doesn't change the text. This is a template I just bought.

[Image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ0Mh.jpg)

I tried to change the text 'Are you want to Donate' to 'Do you want to Donate' but it doesn't change.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#cause-share").jsSocials({
                showLabel: false,
                showCount: false,

            $(document).on('click', '#pay-next', function () {
                var amo = $('#amount').val();
                if (!isNaN(amo) && amo > 0) {
                    $('#payment-details').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#deposit-method').show();
                    $('#back-btn').show();
                    $(document).on('click', '.deposit_button', function () {
                        var gId = $(this).data('id');
                        var cur = $(this).data('currency');
                        var paymentGate = $(this).data('val');
                        var amount = parseFloat($('#amount').val());
                        var name = $('#name').val();
                        var phone = $('#phone').val();
                        var email = $('#email').val();
                        var description = $('#description').val();
                        var causeId = {{$item->id}};
                        $('#deposit-method').css('display', 'none');
                        $('#donate-popup').css('display', 'none');
                        $('#back-btn').css('display', 'none');
                        $('#gt_preview').show();
$('#deposit-text').text('Are You Want to Donate ' + amount + ' ' + cur + ' ?');                                            

$('#accinfo').text('Please Send Total ' + amount + ' ' + cur + ' to');
```

This is the result is shows "Are you want to Donate"?

[Image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ0Mh.jpg)

It should be "Do you want to Donate?"

Comment: $('#deposit-text').text('Do You Want to Donate ' + amount + ' ' + cur + ' ?');
                        $('#accinfo').text('Please Send Total ' + amount + ' ' + cur + ' to');

Comment: The script you posted still contains "`Are You Want to Donate`" is this before or after you did change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing out both your Browser and Laravel App's cache, to clear Laravel's cache `cd` into your project and run:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

As mentioned in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37503726/8740349); In order to avoid the parsing of Blade files on each reload, Laravel caches the views after Blade is processed. I've experienced some situations where the source (view file) is updated but the cache file is not "reloaded". In these cases, all you need to do is to delete the cached views and reload the page.

The cached view files are stored in the `storage/framework/views` directory.

Comment: https://imgur.com/4jxEKnZ

I tried to delete all the cached view files storage/framework/views and clear cache in my browser https://imgur.com/k64Ad3a but still it shows "Are you want to donate"?.

how to cd my project in cpanel?

Comment: https://imgur.com/A8IYW5t I tried in ssh access

Comment: Your snapshot shows "`Could not find input file: artisan`" message, which means either you could not correctly `cd` into your projects directory, or your project is missing the `artisan` file.

Comment: I already tried clear those 3 and it was successfully cleared but still didnt change the text.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it there's another file which is the footer blade php file and change the text there and after that I cleared the laravel's cache