# Blade view does not reflects the changes i made

Tags: php, laravel

i need your help, i am leaning laravel and run into a problem with registering new a new user. I discovered the problem but the problem is that the change i made to the register.blade.php wont reflect in browser, the problem was that instead of `name="usename` i had `name="Username"` and thats it, even after deleting the view, the register page is still there, i tried some commads like `php artisan cache"clear` `php artisan view"clear` `composer dumpautoload`, did not work. The file is the classing register.blade.php file with an addition that i added the "username", i will provide you with the changed part if you need something else i will gladly provide it. Thank you in advance.

```
 <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="Username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{‌{ __('Username') }}</label>

 <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="Username" type="text" class="form-control @error('Username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{‌{ old('Username') }}" required autocomplete="Username" autofocus>

     @error('Username')
       <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
              strong>{‌{ $message }}</strong>
       </span>
     @enderror
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: How that possible? Check, something wrong from your end. May be you are working on a project and delete that page from another project

Comment: This Stack post might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503627/blade-view-not-reflecting-changes

Answer (score 0):

See my comment below your question. A couple of things not mentioned in the post I referenced aree:

1. You may not have updated the remote webserver. Your setup might be like mine: Vagrant box locally, github for code repository, and remote server linked to github. So workflow is:

A. Blade code change
B. Reflects on local machine
C. Git commit
D. Git push
E. Git pull to remote server.

Occasionally, I have forgotten step 5 and stared in disbelief at the browser. Normally when I am tired. Unlikely, but worth a thought.

2. The web route is not loading the blade view you think.

Comment: i am not using git/github for this one

Comment: hi everyone, sorry for the delay, it somehow fixed itself, so it is ok now

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are calling the view you are expecting.

defaults routes are :

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
$this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
$this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the view, when i inspect the register view in chrome and change the manuály the name="Username" for name="username" everything works fine, it's just that the changes I made in my vscode won't reflect in chrome