# Laravel view allways the same

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've started learning laravel and ive a controller with different views:

```
class CompanyController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->middleware('auth');

    }

    public function index() {

        return view('company.index');

    }

    public function show(Company $company)
    {

        if($company->userHasEditAccess())
        {

            return view('company.shows', compact('company'));

        }

        return redirect('home');

    }

    public function showEdit(Company $company)
    {

        if($company->userHasEditAccess())
        {

            return view('company.edit', compact('company'));

        }

        return redirect('home');

    }
}
```

However, all views look the same, but they have different code.
Every view is extended by a master, if I change the html within the master, it will be displayed. But if I change e.g. `index.blade.php`, the change isn't shown in the Browser. Regardless on which device.

I've done all the solutions I've found on the internet:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

- the PHPstorm solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42534996/2453148
- manually deleting all files from the storage chache
- disable browser caching

Hopefully you can help me :)

Example of a view:

```
@extends ('layouts.master')

@section ('content')

    <div class="block-header">

        ...

    </div>


@endsection

@section ('morecss')

    <!-- Morris Chart Css-->
    <link href="{{ asset('/plugins/morrisjs/morris.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />

@endsection

@section ('morejs')

    <!-- Select Plugin Js -->
    <script src="{{ asset('/plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- Slimscroll Plugin Js -->
    <script src="{{ asset('/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js') }}"></script>

    ...


@endsection
```

Comment: Are your view files properly extending from the master layout?

Comment: I've added an example of a view

Comment: And your `layouts.master` has `@yield("content")`?

Comment: thats true it has @yield('content') and the other two

Comment: Everything looks right on that front. How do your routes look? Does the right route connect to the right function? I.e. `mysite/edit` to `public function showEdit()`, etc.

Comment: Yes. Even if I make a change in the view that causes in an error the site will output the error, but if the change is ok it doenst output it.

Comment: Example of a route: `Route::get('/editcompany/{company}', 'CompanyController@showedit');`

Comment: Hmm yeah, that looks ok too. Does your `$company` have `userHasEditAccess()`? I.e. are you being redirected to `/home`? Sidenote: Try to keep the case consistent (`showEdit` vs `showedit`); likely doesn't matter, but has caused issues for me in different environments.

Comment: I cant explain Why, but I've deleted all files from the cach I think the 5th time and now it's working...

But thank you for your help

Comment: Haha. Every once in a while, it just works. Though I still suspect you were being redirected; maybe you picked a different `$company`, which didn't redirect? Who knows.

Comment: Who knows... :)

Do you have an advice for me how I can remove the duplicate of code in function show and showedit and make it in one ?

Comment: As is I think it's ok to have duplicated code; they return different views, so you'd have to account for that somehow. Easiest way I could think of would be a middleware to check that permission, and redirect to home. It would be called before anything in the Controller does, so you'd be able to remove that code completely. Check out middleware here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware