# Laravel views are not updating

Tags: php, laravel

I created a project on a subdomain. After buying a proper domain i copied the files from the subdomain http://lyrics.codencolors.com to the main domain http://lirically.com. Both of the website are hosted on the same server.

- I am developing the project on phpstorm.
- The database of the both the project is same

Routes and controller are working fine and are showing changes but the view are not showing any changes.

I've tried the following things.

=> Cleared the cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

=> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42534996/2444299 (unchecked the option `Preserve files timestamps`)

=> Deleted the cached view inside `storage/framework/views`

=> Renamed the file (it is not getting detected in the controller)

=> Used View::make('lyrics.single') [update]

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: A few things come to my mind: 
Did you symlinked the storage folder?
Have you deleted the PHP OpCache?

Comment: no i haven't symlinked

Comment: opcache is not checked in the server

Comment: What about permission to write. Are you using apache or/and PHP-FPM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the Browser's Cache. It was not getting cleared after the update it got fixed.